# How can I pass arguments to a callback function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a callback function that I wish to pass a pair of integers such as (0,0), (3,0), (3,3), etc. This is what I have at the moment:

```
const onLeftRotationCallback = (r, c) => {
       let newBoard = LeftRotate(r, c, board).slice();

        setBoard(newBoard);
        //reset();
        
    };
```

Where the callback is used:

```
<button onClick={() => props.onLeftRotationCallback(0, 0)}>Rotate left</button>
```

I want r, c to hold the values 0, and 0, respectively in this case.

Passing it as a prop:

```
<TopMessage nextColor={nextColor}
                            winnerColor={winnerColor}
                            haveAWinner={haveAWinner}
                            reset={reset}
                            onLeftRotationCallback={onLeftRotationCallback}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function just as you do on your button `onClick={() => props.onLeftRotationCallback(0, 0)}`:

```js
onLeftRotationCallback={() => onLeftRotationCallback(0, 0)}
```